# How to enlarge ROI imagej macro

Tags: macros, selection, imagej, roi

I would like to enlarge several rois with the following loop:

```
counts=roiManager("count");
 for(i=0; i<counts; i++) {
    roiManager("Select", i);
    run("Enlarge...", "enlarge=10");
 }
```

However, I can’t figure out, what’s wrong with this macro.

Comment: Interestingly, if I skipp "enlarge=10"; I am asked for each ROI by how much I would like to enlarge it; and it works fine...

Comment: Interestingly, when I run the macro it ignores the "enlarge=10". It allways uses a default of "enlarge=15", but I can change the value manually in the menu Edit>Selection>Enlarge...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code enlarges every ROI by 10 pixels, but does not store the new ROI in the ROI manager. You are missing the `roiManager("Update");` command, which you get when running the [macro recorder](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-31.html#sub%3aRecord...) while clicking the *Update* button in the ROI Manager window.

```
counts=roiManager("count");
for(i=0; i<counts; i++) {
    roiManager("Select", i);
    run("Enlarge...", "enlarge=10");
    roiManager("Update");
}
```